# How can a text can be moved with the mouse pointer on an image when hovering in css or html without using JQuery

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move a text with mouse pointer in an image with CSS or Javascript. There are solutions in JQuery, but I am trying to see if there is a solution in CSS or JS. The text is static and not moving, but it need to move with the mouse pointer.

```css
#box {
    width: 100%;
}
.image {
  display: block;
  width: 40%;
  z-index: 1;
}
#TextHidden {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
    left: 100px;
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#box:hover #TextHidden {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"> 
  <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/vaqar/image/upload/v1499826226/DSC_0361_y3mv4r.jpg" class="image"> </img>
  <div id="TextHidden">Hovering</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let screenLog = document.querySelector('#screen-log');
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', logKey);

function logKey(e) {
    placeDiv(e.screenX, e.screenY);
    placeDiv(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  screenLog.innerText = `
    Screen X/Y: ${e.screenX}, ${e.screenY}
    Client X/Y: ${e.clientX}, ${e.clientY}`;
}
        
 function placeDiv(x_pos, y_pos) {
  var d = document.getElementById('TextHidden');
  d.style.position = "absolute";
  d.style.left = x_pos+'px';
  d.style.top = y_pos+'px';
}
```

```css
#box {
    width: 40%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
}  
.image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}  
#TextHidden {
    display: none;
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#box:hover #TextHidden {
   display: block;
}
#screen-log {
    z-index: 11; 
}
```

```html
<div id="box"> 
  <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/vaqar/image/upload/v1499826226/DSC_0361_y3mv4r.jpg" class="image"></p> </img>
  <div id="TextHidden">Hovering<p id="screen-log"></p></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

- First use `position:absolute;` instead of relative for text which you want to display on image.
- And for parent use `display:flex;` if you want height is automatically adjust with you content.

```css
    #box {
    width: 40%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
}
.image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
#TextHidden {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#box:hover #TextHidden {
    display: block;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="box"> 
  <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/vaqar/image/upload/v1499826226/DSC_0361_y3mv4r.jpg" class="image"> </img>
  <div id="TextHidden">Hovering</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am trying to move the text with the mouse movement.

Comment: @user6642297 for this you need to use jquery mouse event. Please see this link for more understanding https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_mousemove.asp

Comment: even in comments no one is answering the answer correctly, I'm also looking for solution to the same

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can make an element drag able by just using CSS , some jquery or java script is needed  [Check out this article for more info on this](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/)